# Populating data into a table with only one field from another table - doable?

Tags: sql

I need to populate a data into a new DB table, B. One column is a foreign key of an existing table, A. The data value is different in various profiles' databases. I would like to have a script to handle the data population on all DBs. The following sql statement doesn't work.

```
INSERT INTO B (id, field2, field3) VALUES (1, SELECT f2 FROM A a WHERE a.f2 like 'Nest%'), 'availability')
```

Is something doable?

Answer (score 1):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO B (id, field2, field3) 
    SELECT 1, f2, 'availability'
    FROM A a
    WHERE a.f2 like 'Nest%';
```

To be honest, I don't know why `insert . . . values` is so widely taught.  You can almost always use `insert . . . select` to do the same thing -- and much, much more.

Comment: If I understand your query correctly, it is INSERT INTO B (id, field2, field3) VALUES (
    SELECT 1, a.f2, 'availability'
    FROM A a
    WHERE a.f2 like 'Nest%'); That doesn't work due to a syntax error